# Should I use my object as Dictionary key value or concatenated string

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have the following class

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int Id1 {get;set;}
    public int Id2 {get;set;}
    public int Id3 {get;set;}

    public MyObject(int id1, int id2, int id3)
    {
      this.Id1 = id1;
      this.Id2 = id2;
      this.Id3 = id3;
    }
}
```

I want to create a list of objects in a Dictionary. Am I best doing it this way

```
Dictionary<MyObject, MyObject> dictionary = new Dictionary<MyObject,MyObject>();

MyObject object1 = new MyObject(1,2,3);
MyObject object2 = new MyObject(2,2,3);
MyObject object3 = new MyObject(2,2,3);

if(!dictionary.ContainsKey(object1))
  dictionary.Add(object1,object1);

if(!dictionary.ContainsKey(object2))
  dictionary.Add(object2,object2);

if(!dictionary.ContainsKey(object3))
  dictionary.Add(object3,object3);
```

Or should I create a Dictionary with the key being a string, and containing the concatenated strings.  For example

```
Dictionary<string, MyObject> dictionary2 = new Dictionary<string,MyObject>();

string key = object1.Id1 + "|" + object1.Id2 + "|" + object1.Id3;

if(!dictionary2.ContainsKey(key ))
  dictionary2.Add(key ,object1);
```

Comment: You need to override `GetHashCode` and `Equals`, then you're good with using your own object

Comment: what you want is a hashset not dictionary.

Comment: The first version is pointless. To lookup the object you must already have it to use it as the key?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. Why do you want to use dictionary in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems what you want is a Hashset since key and value are same and you don't want duplicates.

You will need this class that tells which objects are equal.

```
class MyObjectEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyObject>
{
    MyObjectEqualityComparer()
    {
    }

    public static readonly MyObjectEqualityComparer Default = new MyObjectEqualityComparer();

    public bool Equals(MyObject x, MyObject y)
    {
        return x.Id1 == y.Id1 && x.Id2 == y.Id2 && x.Id3 == y.Id3;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(MyObject obj)
    {
        return obj.Id1.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Id2.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Id3.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

then make a hashset

```
HashSet<MyObject> set = new HashSet<MyObject>(MyObjectEqualityComparer.Default);


MyObject object1 = new MyObject(1,2,3);
MyObject object2 = new MyObject(2,2,3);
MyObject object3 = new MyObject(2,2,3);


if(set.Add(object1))
{
   // item was added.
}
else
{
   // item already exist.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. override `Equals` + `GetHashCode` in `MyObject` or
2. pass a custom `IEqualityComparer<MyObject>` to the dictionary constructor

But it doesnt make sense to store this object as key and as value. Maybe you want to use a `HashSet<MyObject>` instead.